# Simplify the boolean expression F=(Not B and Not C) or (B and Not C) or (Not A and C)

Tags: math, boolean-logic

I need to simplify this expression. I know the answer must be (Not A or Not C) but I keep getting C or (Not A and C)

Comment: This is a good time to use a [Truth Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) diagram (column for each A,B,C,F; 8 rows). What does it show? It can be used to reduce and show equivalency, as to verify the expected/presumed answer. Also, ensure to show work..

Comment: The given answer is correct - how do you arrive at yours?

Answer (score 1):

Tried this in Lua:

```
local a = false
local b = true
local c = true

local f = (not b and not c) or (b and not c) or (not a and c)
local f_= not c or (not a and c)

print(f, f_)
```

Output: false, false
I also tried all the possibilities with all three variables and both 'f' and 'f_' remained identical.

```
F = (Not B and Not C) or (B and Not C) or (Not A and C)
-> (Not B and Not C) or (B and Not C) == Not C
F  = Not C or (Not A and C)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using Karnaugh maps for boolean simplification:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

For your example, we build a 2D truth table:

[image: Empty karnaugh map]

Then fill in the terms from your question, they all get 'or'd together:

[image: Terms in karnaugh map]

Then you find the smallest number of squares/rectangles that cover the needed parts. The squares and rectangles must have powers of two as a dimension, so 2x2 is ok, 1x4 etc, but not 3x2 for example. These are called 'minterms' and the bigger the square, the simpler the boolean expression they represent. In the example below, the minterm for 'not C' wraps off one end of the map and on to the other, but is still considered a 2x2 square.

[image: Minterms]

You can also do it by covering the unused space with 'maxterms', and then invert it again to get the original expression:

[image: Maxterms]

The results of 'not A or not C' and 'not (A and C)' are equivalent by De Morgan's laws. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: This seems incorrect--Karnaugh maps should use a grey code sequence (00 01 11 10); BC's sequence (00 01 10 11 ) is not grey code

Comment: Corrected. Better late than never!

Answer (score 0):

```
(Not B and Not C) or (B and Not C) or (Not A and C)
  |
  | Distributive Law
  V
((Not B or B) and Not C) or (Not A and C)
  |
  | Complement Law
  V
Not C or (Not A and C)
  |
  |　Absorption Law
  V
Not C or Not A
```

Comment: a few laws are left out, but result is correct